# How do I make an HTML page based on <div> tags fool proof?

Tags: html

I have written an HTML doc based on `<div></div>` by writing an external CSS.
But somehow the appearance settings change when I move on to a new browser.

Also my back-ground color does not get re-sized.Just the text increases/decreases in size when I zoom in/out.

Please help

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Forms</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>

</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
<form>
<div class="st1">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="5"><b>Personal Details</b></font>
</div>

<div class="st2">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="5"><b>Contact Details</b></font>
</div>

<div class="st4">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="5"><b>Login Details</b></font>
</div>

<div class="st3">
  <font face="Times New Roman" size="5"><b>Other Details</b></font>
</div>

<div class="st1a">
 <div style="position:absolute;left:22.5%;TOP:2;height:100%">
    First name<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" size="12"><br>  
    <div style="position:relative;top:4%">  
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
    </div>      
    <div style="position:relative;top:7%">  
        <select name="Day">
        <option selected="selected">-DAY-</option>
        <script language="javascript">
        for(i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
            document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
        }

        </script>
        </select>

        <select name="Month">
        <option selected="selected">-MONTH-</option>
        <option>Jan</option>
        <option>Feb</option>
        <option>Mar</option>
        <option>Apr</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>Jun</option>
        <option>Jul</option>
        <option>Aug</option>
        <option>Sep</option>
        <option>Oct</option>
        <option>Nov</option>
        <option>Dec</option>
        </select>

        <select name="Country">
        <option selected="selected">-YEAR-</option>
        <script language="javascript">
        for(i = 2000; i >= 1950; i--){
            document.write("<option value='"+i+"'>"+i+"</option>");
        }

        </script>  
        </select>
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;top:11%"> 
        <select name="Country">
        <option selected="selected">-Select a country-</option>
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Germany</option>
        <option>France</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:13%"> 
        <input type="text" name="SS">
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:13%"> 
        <font size="2">Mandatory for people living in United States Of America</font>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:13.5%">   
        <input type="text" name="SS">
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:19.5%">   
        <select name="Area">
        <option selected="selected">-Select Area-</option>
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Germany</option>
        <option>France</option>
        </select>

          <input type="text" name="SS">  
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:26%"> 
     <input type="text" name="SS">  
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;top:26%"> 
     <font size="2">Please enter the Promo Code.if you have come to this <br>page as a part of promotion.</font>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div style="position:absolute;left:45%;TOP:2;height:100%">
    Middle name<br>
    <input type="text" name="middlename" size="12">     
 </div>
 <div style="position:absolute;left:67%;TOP:2;height:100%">
    Last name<br>
    <input type="text" name="Lastname" size="12">   
 </div>

 <div style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:5%">
  <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;Name<br><br>
  <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;Gender<br><br>
  <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;Date Of Birth<br><br>
  <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;Citizenship<br><br>
  <font >&nbsp;Social Security#</font><br><br>
  <font >&nbsp;Social Insurance#</font><br><br>
  <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;How did you<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hear about us?<br><br>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Promo Code 
 </div>

</div>


<div class="st2a">
 <div style="position:absolute;left:30%;height:100%">
    <div style="position:relative;top:4%">  
      <input type="text" name="address" size="35"><br>
      <input type="text" name="address2" size="35">
    </div>      
    <div style="position:relative;top:6%">  
      <input type="text" name="city">
    </div>      

    <div style="position:relative;top:9%">  
      <input type="text" name="state">
    </div>      

    <div style="position:relative;top:13%"> 
      <input type="text" name="zip">
    </div>      
    <div style="position:relative;top:17%"> 
        <select name="country" style="Width:250px">
        <option selected="selected" >-Select a country-</option>
        <option>India</option>
        <option>Germany</option>
        <option>France</option>
        </select>
    </div>      
    <div style="position:relative;top:22.5%">   
       <input type="text" name="country" size="6">  
       <input type="text" name="area" size="6">  
       <input type="text" name="phone" size="12">  
    </div>      
    <div style="position:relative;top:25%"> 
       <input type="text" name="country" size="5">  
     <input type="text" name="phone">  
    </div>      
<div style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:59%;height:100%">
Country
</div>      
<div style="position:absolute;left:30%;top:59%;height:100%">
Area
</div>      
<div style="position:absolute;left:60%;top:59%;height:100%">
Phone#
</div>      


 </div>

 <div style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:5%">    
 <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;Home Address<br><br><br>
 <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp; City<br><br>
 <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp;State<br><br>  
 <font color="red">*</font>&nbsp; Zip/Postal Code<br><br> 
 <font color="red">*</font> Country Of Residence<br><br>  
 <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;Phone<br><br>  
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile  
 </div>
</div>

<div class="st3a">
     <div style="position:absolute">
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:5%"> 
            <input type="text" name="user">     
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:5.5%">   
             <font size="2">The id for login.Minimum 6 characters</font>    
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:6%"> 
            <input type="text" name="email">     
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:6.5%">   
            <font size="2">Your e-mail id for communication purposes.</font>
         </div>
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:8%"> 
            <input type="password" name="pwd">     
         </div>
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:15%">    
            <input type="password" name="pwd">     
         </div>
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:15.5%">  
            <font size="2">8 to 16 characters with atleast one numeric digit and no spaces.<br>The password is case sensitive.</font>
         </div>

     </div>

    <div style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:7.5%">    
     <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;User Id<br><br>     
     <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;E-mail Id<br><br><br>       
       <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;Password<br><br>
       <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;Re-type Password     
    </div>
</div>

<div class="st4a">
     <div style="position:absolute">
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:5%"> 
             <input type="text"  name="Q"> 
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:5%"> 
            <font size="2">The id for login.Minimum 6 characters<br>Example-What is your mother's birth place?</font>
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:16%">    
             <input type="text"  name="Q"> 
        </div>      
        <div style="position:relative;left:40%;top:16%">    
        <small>The Hint answer is case sensitive.Please keep the Hint Question and<br> Answer different from the User id.</small> 
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute;left:0%;top:7.5%">    
     <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;Hint Question<br><br><br><br> 
     <font color="red">*</font> &nbsp;Hint Answer 
    </div>


</div>

<div style="left:45%;bottom:13%;position:absolute">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>

</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**And here is my STYLE SHEET**

```
    .st1{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
left:0%;
top:0%;
background-color:Orange;
text-align:left; 
width:49.5%;
Height:4%
}

.st1a{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
left:0%;
top:4%;
background-color:#FFE6CD;
text-align:left; 
width:49.5%;
height:45%
}

.st2{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
right:0%;
top:0%;
background-color:Orange;
text-align:left; 
width:50%;
Height:4%
}

.st2a{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
right:0%;
top:4%;
background-color:#FFE6CD;
text-align:left; 
width:50%;
Height:45%
}

.st3{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
right:0%;
top:49.5%;
background-color:Orange;
text-align:left; 
height:4%;
width:50%
}

.st3a{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
left:0%;
top:53%;
background-color:#FFE6CD;
text-align:left; 
height:31%;
width:49.5%
}

.st4{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
left:0%;
top:49.5%;
background-color:Orange;
text-align:left; 
height:4%;
width:49.5%
}

.st4a{
position:absolute;
margin:1;
right:0%;
top:53%;
background-color:#FFE6CD;
text-align:left; 
height:31%;
width:50%
}
```

Comment: post your code.. or link to it..

Comment: my code is too huge.is it ok if i post it?

Comment: +1. That's what I would like to know.

Comment: Can Anybody point out the mistakes in my code.I know there must be way too many,but still I want to know,as I'm just an amateur and I would want to know what I've done wrong so that I can work on improvising it.

Comment: Thanx a lot guys. I did some more research on CSS and all your comments helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do use a Doctype (that triggers standards mode)
- Do not use anything other than `position: static` (the default) except with great caution. Normal flow is your friend
- Do [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)
- Do not use the `style` attribute
- Do use class names and ids that have some meaning
- Do use semantic markup such as `<label>` and not presentational markup such as `<b>` and `<font>`
- Do make sure the content makes sense without stylesheets (e.g. don't have a label in one part of a document and a field in a completely different part of a document and then try to use CSS to link them together)
- Do not use client side JavaScript to generate important content (such as the content of a `<select>` element)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1) Learn HTML/CSS really well, test in every major browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari) and fix as needed

2) Do not write any HTML/CSS, write in another language/environment that can generate HTML as output, essentially pushing browser compatibility worries into the middle layer so that you don't have to worry about it.  Not sure if a 100% fool proof solution like that exists; maybe [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at something like [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), which should start all browsers off on the same footing, and *then* you apply your style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you put fixed width in the `div` that contains the color and that's why when zooming the `div` the size remains same.  ALso, I think you are not zooming in/out, rather you are just resizing the browser. Please mention the browser name, so that everyone can get a better idea of what you're seeing. Also please follow [what MK said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4512296/102067).

Comment: I coded it and checked it in google chrome in college.but @ home I have tried to check the same on chrome anf the output is different.Does the size  of the monitor also make a difference.I'm new to HTML so I don't know much

Comment: monitor size actually doesn't make any difference. If you DOM width is bigger then monitor size then it will just add an scroll-er at the bottom of your browser. One more thing I have checked your css, I have found like you put width and height in your css for div thatswhy when u are zooming in the div remains the same height. Thanks and best of luck.